# Implementing the Index operator for matrices with multiple parameters

Tags: struct, rust

I'm trying to make a `Matrix` struct and I want to override the `Index` operator to let me have matrix-style indexing.

For example:

```
let m = Matrix { ... DATA ... }
let entry = m[0,0]
```

My structure looks like this:

```
struct Matrix {
    cols: usize,
    rows: usize,
    data: Vec<f32>
}
```

I've been looking at the [Index trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Index.html) and I don't see how I can make this work? Additionally I'd like to be able to take ranges in each dimension etc.

Comment: How is this a matrix? A matrix would have a Vec<Vec<f32>> not just one vector.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In short, you cannot do this. The [`Index` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/ops/trait.Index.html) is defined as:

```
pub trait Index<Idx: ?Sized> {
    type Output: ?Sized;
    fn index(&self, index: Idx) -> &Self::Output;
}
```

That is, it takes a *single* argument of type `Idx`. The closest you can do is to use a tuple, which is a single type with multiple values packed into it:

```
impl std::ops::Index<(usize, usize)> for Matrix {
    type Output = f32;

    fn index(&self, idx: (usize, usize)) -> &f32 {
        // or as appropriate for row- or column-major data       
        &self.data[idx.0 * self.cols + idx.1]
    }
}
```

And it would be called like

```
matrix[(0, 1)]
```

[bluss points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770989/implementing-the-index-operator-for-matrices-with-multiple-parameters/33771089?noredirect=1#comment55309751_33771089) that the [multiarray crate](https://github.com/sellibitze/multiarray) uses two-element arrays instead of a tuple. This is probably easier to type as you can just hit the square brackets twice:

```
impl std::ops::Index<[usize; 2]> for Matrix {
    type Output = f32;

    fn index(&self, idx: [usize; 2]) -> &f32 {
        // or as appropriate for row- or column-major data       
        &self.data[idx[0] * self.cols + idx[1]]
    }
}
```

And it's called like `matrix[[0, 1]]`. The important thing is that there's still just a single value provided as the argument to `index`.

Repeat the implementation as desired for [`Range`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html), [`RangeTo`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeTo.html), [`RangeFrom`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html), and [`RangeFull`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html). These are all single types, so you can call it like `matrix[5..]`, for whatever that might mean.

Comment: Using arrays instead of tuples is a nice trick I saw from [multiarray](https://github.com/sellibitze/multiarray). `matrix[[0, 1]]` looks good and is easier to type.

Comment: @bluss mmm, neat indeed! You want I should add it in here, or do you want to have a separate answer?

Comment: Here is fine, I thought it's just a minor detail.

Comment: @bluss: I’d do tuples rather than arrays there. Probably my Python background speaking there, where `foo[bar, baz]` is `foo.__getitem__((bar, baz))`. (Python does a lot of permitting parenthesis omission with tuples, e.g. `foo, bar = baz`, `foo = bar, baz`. Rust doesn’t do any, for now at least.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's a shame this can't be done as in most other languages but the array solution works nicely.

Comment: Sorry for off topic: Could you list some of these "most other" languages? AFAIK it's not possible in Java, C and C++ to name three big ones...

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: The nice thing about arrays as index is that you can rely on `[usize; N]` implementing `AsRef<[usize]>` in generic code to support multiple dimensions more easily. I think if you want to go with tuples you would have to do more special casing for the dimensions. Of course, if you are restricted to 2D, this does not make a difference. But it would be nice to be consistent between different numbers of dimensions. (I'm the author of the multiarray crate, btw)

Comment: @Shepmaster , Could you possibly have an answer to add Indexing to an actual matrix?

Answer (score 14):

Another possibility would be to use 2D-array style indexing like `m[0][1]`. This is definitely possible -- even quite easy in your case. Your `Index` implementation just has to return something that is indexable again. Code:

```
use std::ops::Index;

struct Matrix {
    cols: usize,
    rows: usize,
    data: Vec<f32>
}

impl Index<usize> for Matrix {
    type Output = [f32];
    fn index(&self, index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.data[index * self.cols .. (index+1) * self.cols]
    }
}

fn main() {
    let m = Matrix {
        cols: 2,
        rows: 2,
        data: vec![1., 2., 3., 4.],
    };

    println!("{} {}", m[0][0], m[0][1]);
    println!("{} {}", m[1][0], m[1][1]);
}
```

This style is more common among languages like Java and C.